# Request Timed Out if pinging some websites

Tags: ping

I am puzzled in this situation. 
My computer is able to open some websites but not everyone. For example it is able to open Google and Facebook but not Yahoo and Microsoft. I tried to ping Yahoo.com but request timed out, so i tried to ping the ip address of yahoo and still same. Plz help.

Comment: Can you access the sites via a proxy?